# What is the difference between $T^{-1}T$ and $T^{-1}(Tu)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Right now, I'm reading Linear Algebra Done Right. It's said that if $T^{-1}$ is an inverse of $T$, then

> $T^{-1}T=I$

where $I$ is the identity map. Then in the next example it gives an equation

> $T^{-1}(Tu)=u$

where u is in the domain of T.

I got confused by the two equations above. From the first equation, it seems that the product of two linear maps ends up to be a linear map, whereas the second equation shows that the product of two linear maps ends up to be an variable. I was wondering what I miss here?

Comment: $u$ is a vector.

Comment: By the definition of composition of functions $$T^{-1}(Tu)=(T^{-1}T)(u)=I(u)=u.$$

Comment: The second equation says that the product (composition) of a map and its inverse when applied to an element of the domain of the map gives the same element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no products here. The equality $T^{-1}T=\operatorname{Id}$ means that the *composition* of $T^{-1}$ and $T$ is the identity map. The equality $T{-1}\bigl(T(u)\bigr)=u$ means that the map $T^{-1}T$ maps vector $u$ to itself.